# Firefox fails to securely connect to Google services at random times [Ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: 16.04, firefox

Ever since yesterday, when I try to access Google or Youtube or Google Images, sometimes the page won't load and it will say that secure connection failed and display the following message:

```
SSL_ERROR_RX_MALFORMED_SERVER_HELLO
```

It has only happened few times so far and whenever I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> the page just loads normally, but I'm still concerned. I tried to look for solutions online but every topic was Windows specific. Is there something wrong?

Comment: o/t, but I've been having this issue on macOS too.  (this was the first thing Google brought up for me).  I don't think it's platform-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Firefox? This appears to be a FF bug:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1462303

Be aware that this can also be caused by something getting in the way of your traffic, either good-natured things like intrusion prevention systems or bad things like malware.

Answer (score -1):

Set `security.tls.version.max = 3` in `about:config`

> 3 will use TLS 1.2
>
> 4 will use TLS 1.3